# Script to Email Me If a File Exists at a Certain Time

Tags: shell, email

I need to know how to write a korn shell script that will email me at a certain time (specifically 11:00 am) if a file exists.  And I need to use $? to check to see if I can find the file ~/log_1100.txt first before the script emails me the results.  I am using Linux Ubuntu 13.10.  Below is what I have so far;

## !/usr/bin/ksh

$~/log_1100.txt=”/tmp/users”
if [ $?==0 ]; then
    echo "That file exists."
else
    echo "That file does not exist."
fi

cat $~/log_1100.txt | mailx -s "Existance of Log File" email@email.com

Answer (score 0):

```
now=$(date +"%T")

if [ -f testfile && now == 11:00:00] then
echo testfile exists!
mail -s "a subject" someone@somewhere.com
fi
```

My shell scripting is a little rusty...

Hope it helps!